# Creating a query where no join exists

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a query that if there is a join, averages the difference between the created and canceled date.  The query is below

```
select  avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, users.created_at,subscriptions.canceled_at)) as total from users
join subscriptions on users.id = subscriptions.user_id
```

What I am trying to do is if there is no join use NOW() instead off canceled_at and then averaging both mysql queries to get an average of the days.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `left join` should do the trick:

```
SELECT   AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, 
                           users.created_at, 
                           COALESCE(subscriptions.canceled_at, NOW())) AS total
FROM      users
LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON users.id = subscriptions.user_id
```